# How to create a test class for a java project

Tags: java

I have created a `Browser` class for my project. I now need to extend this project and therefore need to create a suitable test plan and test class.

How do I create this test class?

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Browser here.
 * 
 * @author (johnson) 
 * @version (10/12/13)
 */

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

public class Browser
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int iD;
    private String email;
    private int yearOfBirth;
    private boolean memberID;
    private WineCase wineCase;
    private boolean loggedIn;
    private Website website;
    private boolean discount;
    private List<Boolean> baskets = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

 /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Browser
     */
    public Browser()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        wineCase = null;
        website = null;
        iD = 00065;
        yearOfBirth = 1992;
        memberID = true;
        discount = false;
    }

 /**
  * Constructor for objects of class Browser
  */
 public Browser(String newEmail,int newYearOfBirth)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        wineCase = null;
        website = null;
        iD = 0;
        email = newEmail;
        yearOfBirth = newYearOfBirth;
        loggedIn = false;
        memberID = true;
        discount = false;
    }

 /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Browser
     */
    public Browser(int newID, String newEmail,int newYearOfBirth)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        wineCase = null;
        website = null;
        iD = newID;
        email = newEmail;
        yearOfBirth = newYearOfBirth;
        memberID = true;
        discount = false;
    }

     /**
     * returns the ID
     */

    public int getId()
    {
    return iD;
    }


    /**
     * gets the email of the browser class
     */

    public String getEmail()
    {
    return email;
    }

    public boolean getDiscount()
    {
        return discount;
    }


    /**
     * gets the yearOfBirth for the browser class
     */

    public int yearOfBirth()
    {
    return yearOfBirth;
    }

    public double getWineCost()
    {
        return wineCase.getWineCost();
    }

      public double getWineCase()
    {
        return wineCase.getWineCost();
    }

     /**
     * returns 
     */

    public void setLoginStatus(boolean status)
    {
       loggedIn = status;
    }

    /**
     * returns 
     */

    public void selectWineCase(WineCase winecase)
    {
    wineCase = winecase;
    System.out.println ("Browser "+getId()+" has selcted wine case"+wineCase.getRefNo()+ "of "+winecase.getNoOfBottles()+ wineCase.getDescription()+ " at £"+wineCase.getWineCost()); 
    }

     /**
     * returns
     */

    public void payForWine()
    {
      website.checkout(this);  
    }

    public void setId()
    {
        iD = 999;
    }

     public void setWebSite(Website website)
    {
        this.website = website;
    }

    public void setDiscount(boolean discount)
    {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    public ArrayList<WineCase> getBasket(WineCase wineCase)
     {
        this.wineCase = wineCase;
        System.out.println ("Browser "+getId()+" has selcted wine case"+wineCase.getRefNo()+ "of "+wineCase.getNoOfBottles()+ wineCase.getDescription()+ " at £"+wineCase.getWineCost()); 
    }
}
```

Any answers/replies would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Write a class with a `main` method

Answer (score 3):

You can use a unit testing framework as http://junit.org/. There are numerous examples on the internet.

An example unit test would be:

```
public class BrowserTest{

    @Test
    public void testNoArgsConstructor(){
        Browser testedBrowser = new Browser();
        assertNull(testedBrowser.getWineCase());
        assertNull(testedBrowser.getWebsite());
        assertEquals(00065, testedBrowser.getId());
        assertEquals(1992, testedBrowser.getYearOfBirth());
        assertTrue(testedBrowser.getMemberId());
        assertFalse(testedBrowser.isDiscount());
    }

//more tests
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to test your class, use JUnit framework - you will create unit tests (http://junit.org/). It is already included in IDE (Eclipse), just go File → New → JUnit → JUnit Test case.